# For groups and orders show $\forall a,b\in G: |ab|=|ba|$ and $\forall G$ with $|G| = p^n$ for $p$ prime has a subgroup of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

1) $\forall a,b\in G: |ab|=|ba|$.

Let $|ab|=n$, then $(ab)^n=e$. But $(ab)^n=(ba)^n$, so $|ba|=n.$

2) Every group $G$ with $|G| = p^n$ for $p$ prime has a subgroup of order $p$.

Does this follow directly from the fact that the order of subgroup divides order of group? i.e. $p$ divides $p^n$, so there is an element $a\in G$ such that $\langle a\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: It's not true in general that $(ab)^n =(ba)^n$

Comment: Also, Lagrange's theorem (about the divisibility of the order of a group by orders of subgroups) says nothing about the existence of anything. The only thing it says is that if you _have_ a subgroup, then what order that subgroup has is limited to relatively few possible numbers. If you want to prove that a subgroup with some property (like a specific order) exists, then that theorem is of little help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $ab\neq ba$ so you're proof of 1) is not valid without further justification.

For 1) it is sufficient to show that $(ab)^n=e$ implies $(ba)^n=e$ (but this claim of sufficiency requires some proof! you should fill in the details).  Here is a hint:  $e=(ab)^n$ so $a^{-1}=b(ab)^{n-1}=(ba)^{n-1}b$.

For 2) take a non identity element $a$ and generate the cyclic subgroup $\langle a\rangle$.  By Lagrange's theorem, this subgroup has order dividing $p^n$.  Now can you show that a cyclic group of order $p^m$ has an element of order $p$?

Comment: But is a group still cyclic if it is of order $p^n$ and not of order $p$? Can I even apply this fact here?

Comment: Any element generates a cyclic group.  A group is cyclic if it is generated by a single element.  There are cyclic groups of every order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not ask two questions in a single one.

Here is a answer of one of them;

Let $$(ab)^n=abab...ab=e$$
$$=a(baba...ba)b=e$$
$$a(ba)^{n-1}b=e$$
$$(ba)^{n-1}b=a^{-1}$$
$$(ba)^{n-1}ba=e$$
We are done.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can use the fact that $ab = abaa^{-1}$.  What happens when you raise it to the power of $n$?

Comment: Can I say it must be cyclic because the order of $G$ is not $p$ but $p^n$? And $g^1$ had the desired order...

Comment: @user149868, Apologies, apparently I got some wires crossed when I was answering the second portion. I've gone ahead and deleted that part, since it wasn't helpful. But to answer your question: If $|G|=p$, it is indeed cyclic. If $|G|=p^n$, though, it need not be cyclic; for example, $|V_4|=2^2$ and $|D_8|=2^3$, but neither is cyclic.